# ion-nav-buttons full width

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to add search bar into header on one of the page.

```
<ion-view view-title="">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <label class=" item item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </label>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content>
    Search content
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The search bar does show up in the header as expected. But how can I get the search field to be 100% width across the header? I did try to apply:

```
.buttons-left, .left-buttons{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

It does work. But the problem is it affect all other pages as well. I tried to add `class` and `id` to `ion-nav-buttons`, but it doesn't shows up.

How can I apply custom width to `ion-nav-buttons` only on specific page?

Comment: You probably have some parent containers, at least `<body>`. You could add id/class to them then set a width according to the selected class, like: `body.anyclassname ion-nav-buttons { width: 100%; }`. Then you add this class name to <body> only when you want it 100% large.

Comment: Any comments about my suggestion? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is the best place where to put a search field:

```
<ion-nav-buttons>
```

You can define a custom header for your specific view:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear">Cancel</button>
</ion-header-bar>
```

and use the directive `hide-nav-bar="true"` in your view to tell the current view to hide the navbar:

```
<ion-view view-title="home" hide-nav-bar="true">
    ...
</ion-view>
```

This is your end result:

```
<ion-view view-title="home" hide-nav-bar="true">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-bar">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>


  <ion-content padding='true' scroll='false' has-footer='false'>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        HOME PAGE
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

I've also used some styling to change the result:

```
.search-bar
{
  width:100% !important;
  background: inherit;
  height: inherit !important;
}
```

and this is how it looks in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YVCnntce2NHjZzNIjD3o?p=preview).